# Ruby on Rails 4 - How do I iterate through these params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration

I have the following params that are being submitted:

```
{"utf8"=>"âœ“", 
"course"=>
   {
    "title"=>"Test", "roles"=>["Tuesday", "Thursday"]
   }
}
```

My question is: How do I iterate through the "roles" params to "add_role"?

I am currently trying this iteration, but it is not working:

```
@course.user_id = current_user.id

params['course']['roles'].each do |key, value|
  @course.add_role(key['course']['roles'])
end
```

I get the following error: `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

What am I doing wrong with iterarting the params?

Thank you!

Comment: `params['course']['roles']` gives you array, not a hash.

Comment: use .each do |role| ...add_role(role) end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`params['course']['roles']` is the array `["Tuesday", "Thursday"]`, not a hash.

In your loop, `key` takes the value of a role string, `"Tuesday"['course']` returns `nil` and `nil['roles']` causes your error.

You seem to be trying to do this:

```
params['course']['roles'].each do |role|
  @course.add_role(role)
end
```

[image: irb]

Comment: It returns `nil` in my irb... Perhaps it depends on the ruby version?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I added a screenshot. I'm not making this up! haha

Comment: Yes... this is because `str[match_str] → new_str or nil`.. says - *If a match_str is given, that string is returned if it occurs in the string.* :)